# Get error code from AngularFire 2 Auth Signin

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Following is my code for user sign-in in ionic2 using AngularFire2 to Firebase.

```
     this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( 
        login.email,
        login.password
      ).catch(ERROR=>{
        console.log(ERROR);

      });
```

Here the ERROR variable in catch returns with a code and message. I want to get the code but I see only the following options of ERROR.

```
message, name and stack.
```

ERROR.code is not allowed. How do I get the code from ERROR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the error that is in a primitive format to a more specific one, so you can get more information about it.

```
.catch ((error: firebase.FirebaseError) => { console.log(error.code)}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. This will benefit other users as well as the OP. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you so much.